# Weird warning every time I boot my ubuntu Desktop PC

Tags: boot, 22.04, 22.10, loop-device

**The message is:**

> Dev loop0: unable to read RDB block 8

After 1 second Ubuntu boot without any problem.
How can I remove this warning by solving the issue?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1979633